# decodestrings is not an attribute of base64 error in python 3.9.1

Tags: linux, base64, python-3.9

After upgrading from python 3.8.0 to python 3.9.1, the tremc front-end of transmission bitTorrent client is throwing `decodestrings is not an attribute of base64`  error whenever i click on a torrent entry to check the details.

My system specs:
OS: Arch linux
kernel: 5.6.11-clear-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i went to the site-packages directory and with ripgrep tried searching for the `decodestring` string.

```
 rg decodestring
    
    paramiko/py3compat.py
    39:    decodebytes = base64.decodestring
```

Upon examining the py3compat.py file,i found this block:

```
PY2 = sys.version_info[0] < 3

if PY2:
    string_types = basestring  # NOQA
    text_type = unicode  # NOQA
    bytes_types = str
    bytes = str
    integer_types = (int, long)  # NOQA
    long = long  # NOQA
    input = raw_input  # NOQA
    decodebytes = base64.decodestring
    encodebytes = base64.encodestring
```

So decodebytes have replaced(aliased) decodestring attribute of base64 for python version >= 3
This must be a new addendum because tremc was working fine in uptil version 3.8.*.

Opened tremc script, found the erring line (line 441), just replaced the attribute `decodestring` with `decodebytes`.A quick fix till the next update.

PS: Checked the github repository, and there's a [pull](https://github.com/tremc/tremc/issues/99#issue-756272337) request for it in waiting.
If you don't want to  wait for the next release and also don't want to hack the way i did, you can get it freshly build from the repository, though that would be not much of a difference than my method

Answer (score 2):

base64.encodestring() and base64.decodestring(), aliases deprecated since Python 3.1, have been removed.

use base64.encodebytes() and base64.decodebytes()